# Update User to show they have paid - Stripe .Net Core

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, stripe-payments

I'm developing an app that will allow members to book/pay for classes using Stripe. However, I'm finding it difficult to update the application to say that the user has paid successfully or not.

The aim is that when a user pays the payment will be assigned to them and they are able to get a list of payments within their account. 
Below is the code i have within my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PaymentSuccess(Event obj, int memberId, int eventId)
{
    // add member to event attendees? if so just call BookEvent above
    var eventBook = BookEvent(memberId, eventId);
    var result = new { eventBook }; //service.UpdateEventAfterPayment(obj);
    return Json(result);
}

public IActionResult Charge(string stripeEmail, string stripeToken, Event obj)
{
    //var json = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
     var customers = new Stripe.CustomerService();
     var charges = new Stripe.ChargeService();

     var customer = customers.Create(new Stripe.CustomerCreateOptions
     {
       Email = stripeEmail,
       Source = stripeToken
      }) ;

      var charge = charges.Create(new Stripe.ChargeCreateOptions
      {
        Amount = 300,
        Description = "Class Payment",
        Currency="gbp",
        Customer= customer.Id,
        ReceiptEmail= stripeEmail,
        Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"OrderId", "123" },
            {"PostCode", "BT480GY" }
        }
        });

        if(charge.Status == "succeeded")
        {
          string BalanceTransactionId = charge.BalanceTransactionId;
          var email = User.FindFirst("sub")?.Value;
          var customerPaid = charge.Paid;
          customerPaid = true;
          return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
          return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
```

And below is what is in my chtml file:

```
<div id="eventBook" class="text-center">
                        <form asp-action="Charge" asp-controller="Timetable" method="post">
                            <article>
                                <label>Amount: £3.00</label>
                            </article>
                            <script src="//checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"
                                    class="stripe-button"
                                    data-key="@Stripe.Value.PublishableKey"
                                    data.locale="auto"
                                    data-description="Class Charge">
                            </script>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

I am not sure if I'm passing in the correct data from stripe to assign the payment to a specific user, that they can then go on and see a list of transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as charges.Create() does not throw an exception you can assume that the charge succeeded. More on error handling here:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling

After you create the customer, I'd recommend saving the Stripe customer ID to either your database or session. Later, when you want to list the charges made by that customer, you can make the "list charges" API call and pass that customer ID to get only charges for that customer:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list#list_charges-customer

```
var customerID = "cus_1234xxx..."; // Retrieved from session or DB

var options = new ChargeListOptions { Limit = 3, Customer = customerID };
var service = new ChargeService();
StripeList<Charge> charges = service.List(
  options
);
```

Hope that clears things up!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should not be relying on a 1-1 correlation between a Stripe Customer and a user in your system. There's no need for a Stripe customer, unless you're persisting payment sources. Even if you are doing that, it shouldn't necessarily be a requirement that there's a Stripe Customer for every user.

The better approach here is to record the charge id on your end, and associate *that* with the user. Then, you should have a webhook endpoint for Stripe to notify when a charge goes through. When the webhook gets hit, then you can look up the payment/user on your side with that charge id associated with it, and update anything accordingly.